# Google App Engine Project works in Development Environment but not when Deployed

Tags: java, google-app-engine, deployment

I am in the process of moving my web website over to google app engine and am having a problem with my site when it is deployed.  The application was being hosted on tomcat/mysql and predominately consists of jsp pages.  I have read the fallowing google documentation:

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml.html

I am unable to get any of the jsp pages to work correctly I keep getting a 500 Server Error

Error: Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.

The project works great in the google app engine development environment but doesn't work when deployed it seems like the project isn't getting mapped.

Does anyone have any insight.

Comment: What do you see in the Google App Engine log web interface?

Comment: What about the mysql stuff ? What did you do with that ?

Comment: I removed the original mysql statements and replaced them with JDO queries.

Comment: here is a link that seems to describe what I am seeing

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1365

Answer (score 1):

When your app raises an uncaught exception, App Engine shows the generic 500 page. In order to see the exception, you need to check the logs for your app in your app's admin console.

Comment: I have been over the logs a few times and have not seen anything other than these two lines repeated:  Completed update of a new default version; Deployed a new version

Comment: @Eric You're looking at the admin logs, not the request logs. Click on "Logs" under "Main", not "Admin Logs" under "Administration".

Answer (score 1):

So after plenty of research I found the problem to be that some classes that are persisted need to also implement Serializable when you use sessions.  For some reason I didn't see this in the documentation or come across it in my initial research.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have already done this, but you should be able to check if everything is fine locally, by first deploying locally using the app engine development server. http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/devserver.html

Comment: Yes I have definitely tested this in the local google app engine and the application is working well.

Answer (score 0):

If you're testing locally on tomcat + mysql, then you can't deploy on the app engine. The Google App Engine not does support SQL databases. Besides that, if you want a more detailed response you need to look at the app engine logs and tell us why it is throwing a 500 at you.

Comment: No I have ported the application from a mysql/tomcat environment to the local google app engine environment.  The application works fine on google's local app engine environment, but when I push the application to the deployment environment it doesn't work and gives the error stated above